# Estimating the effort for applying architectural research projects to calls for entries by public organisations

Tags: phd, funding, europe

In this year I will become occupied with finding and applying for government grants like open calls by the European Commission (so called "Drittmittelbeschaffung" in Austria). I am working for a department at a university in Austria that focuses on architectural design and urban design. Thus, I will focus on grants supporting work concentrating on culture, society, and architectural and urban design. One of the projects I am looking for grants emerged from my master's thesis, which I completed last year. The other projects are by Ph.D. candidates. Also, I will be looking for ideas for new research proposals based on existing or upcoming calls that match the general orientation of the department.

The details haven't been set yet, but I guess that I will prepare the project that emerged from my master's thesis on my own, while I am only going to support the other Ph.D. candidates with their application.

The department will employ me for this work and as a teaching fellow. However, I have no experience with fund-raising. I would like to know how many hours of work per week I have to expect for finding and applying for funds, so I can figure out if the contract is fair. Are there any rules of thumb or is there a guideline how to estimate this effort? Secondly, what factors impact the amount of needed time most? What is the ratio between the effort required for preparing a project for an application and just supporting others in their application?

**Updated on 2018-11-08 to answer the questions raised by @MassimoOrtolano.**

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by 3rd-party funds and effort? At present, the question is very unclear.

Comment: With 3rd-party funds ("Drittmittelbeschaffung"), I meant applying for existing calls for entries by public organisations like the European Union. I will focus on grants supporting work concentrating on culture, art, design, and society. With effort, I meant how many work hours there is to expect from such a work. This is in particular important to me because I have to figure out how many hours per week this will occupy from my time. I hope the question became clearer.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderGogl -  the response that you gave to Massimo would be useful in the original question - could you please edit the question appropriately?